# Swashbuckler rogue: does sneak attack fail if you have both advantage & disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

I am having a bit of an argument with my DM.

The rules say that you can have sneak attack if "you don’t have disadvantage on the attack roll".

If I have both advantage and disadvantage, that results in a straight roll when attacking. A straight roll suggests that sneak attack is allowed.

My DM interprets it as, if I have a source of disadvantage, regardless of weather I also have advantage or not, the fact I am being disadvantaged in some way prevents sneak attack from triggering.

Can someone please let me know who has the correct interpretation?

Comment: Cool, thanks for doing that. Another question has been found that might answer you question; does this give you the answer you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, the wording clarifies that I am definitely in the right on this one 

Comment: Cool, glad this has helped you out. Although just remember that "the DM is always right", so even though RAW says you're right, they may still choose to rule it their way...